# Delaying Lua function so it runs after Neovim has successfully launched

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I am building a Neovim plug-in with Lua that needs to run a command on the user's terminal to obtain system information. However, this function is causing Neovim to lag at startup. How can I schedule my function to run right after Neovim launches? Can I use `vim.api` to achieve this, or do I need to run the function asynchronously?

Currently, I import the function from a module and call it in the file where I define the user commands with `vim.api.nvim_create_user_command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `vim.schedule()` and `vim.schedule_wrap()` may be what you are looking for. In short, they schedule a function to somewhere later in the event loop when one can access Neovim's API at a time that is "suitable" for Neovim itself.

To delay the call of your function that is causing issues until 2 seconds after Neovim has started, you could do something like this:

```lua
local function start_up_func()
    print("My start-up function here")
end
local function delayed_start_up_func()
    local timer = vim.loop.new_timer()
    -- Delay 2000ms and 0 means "do not repeat"
    timer:start(2000, 0, vim.schedule_wrap(start_up_func))
end
delayed_start_up_func()
```

Alternatively, `vim.schedule` without the delay may resolve the issue(s):

```lua
local function start_up_func()
    print("My start-up function here")
end
vim.schedule(start_up_func)
```

For more information, have a look at the documentation with `h:vim.schedule` and `h:vim.schedule_wrap`. [This video](https://youtu.be/GMS0JvS7W1Y) by TJ DeVries also provides a good overview of these functions and how they can be used.